# Facebook oauth/access_token call works perfectly on local machine, but fails on dev server

Tags: api, facebook, oauth, access-token

Fighting a weird situation.  We are developing a Facebook app and I have run into a strange issue.  When our application sends out the oauth/access_token call, it works perfectly on my local environment, but returns a 400 error when called from our dev server.  I've checked the calls from the two environments against each other and they are identical, yet one works and the other fails completely.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you check what the response body actually contains? Usually there is a human-readable error message in there.

Comment: No body, just a status = 400 in the header

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.